# Selection all data rather than id

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on blogging web application. I won't display the category and slug via article id.

```
$result= mysqli_query($mysqli,'SELECT articleId, articleTitle, articleSlug, 
                                        articleDescrip, articleDate, articleTags 
                                FROM blog_table 
                                ORDER BY articleId DESC');
```

I am selecting these columns from another blog_table. Now, i use the articleId value in another query.

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,'SELECT categoryName, categorySlug   
                                 FROM category, cat_links 
                                 WHERE category.categoryId = cat_links.categoryId 
                                 AND cat_links.articleId = articleId');

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
    echo $row2['categoryName']; 
}
```

In the above query, I select the column from the two other table category and cate_links. The while loop is looping all categories rather than the articleId . 
I want to display the categoryName related to the articleId but it displaying all categories. 
Can you please solve it, how can I display the articleId related category not all categories.

Comment: It woul dbe useful for you to look up and use the [JOIN Syntax in queries like this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Comment: First result1 from another table and second for the only category fetch related to article id but it's fetching all category from category table. I want the related categories with articleId.

Comment: `HINT` : use `JOIN` for this

Comment: I already used  JOIN . Check table images and output and check my query.I want select categoryName and categorySlug related to articleId . Please check all structure then answer.

Comment: I didn't find any join in your query?

Comment: `SELECT c.categoryName, c.categorySlug
FROM category c
INNER JOIN cat_links cl
    ON c.categoryId = cl.categoryId
WHERE
    cl.articleId IN (SELECT articleId FROM blog_table);`

Comment: Can you please tell me, what is the reason? All categories are coming.

Answer (score 0):

You may rephrase by using just a single query:

```
SELECT c.categoryName, c.categorySlug
FROM category c
INNER JOIN cat_links cl
    ON c.categoryId = cl.categoryId
WHERE
    cl.articleId IN (SELECT articleId FROM blog_table);
```

This will return all category metadata from articles which appear in the `blog_table`, with no restrictions at all on that table.  This agrees with the logic you did show us.  If there be some restrictions on `blog_table`, then you should state what they are.

Comment: It's working the same and selecting all categories rather than related to articleId and I am selecting article id from another table blog_table. I want category related to articleId.

Comment: Then tell us what the relationship is between the tables.

Comment: Hey Tim I edit my description and attached table structure for blog_table, category and cat_link tables. I also attached the output . You can check the image.  All categories are coming.  Please check

Comment: Please answer, I have attached complete structure with images